# jquery slidedown alert message?

Tags: jquery

there was this plugin i once saw and i cant find it anymore.
its an alert that has a 100% width of the page and can either slide down from the top or slide up from the bottom. do any of your know what its called? it would probably be simple to make but i just want to see a demo of it.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/29/jbar-a-jquery-notification-plugin/) be what you are after?

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a slide down panel that might work for you. If the code works for you please feel free to use it. I slapped a little demo together here: http://converter.numinous-soft.com/

Comment: than you i'll have a look at it